# Cast return type in postsharp

Tags: c#, .net, aop, postsharp

I want to use PostSharp follow code:

```
class Program
{
    [PostModerator]
    public static ReturnState<Person> GetPerson()
    {
        return new ReturnState<Person>() { Result = new Person { Id = 2, Name = "Gholzam" }, Succeed = true };
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var personAttempt= GetPerson();
        Console.WriteLine("Test ok");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

in PostModerator I use follow code:

```
[Serializable]
public class PostModeratorAttribute : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        args.ReturnValue = new ReturnState<object> { Succeed=false };//Star
        args.FlowBehavior = FlowBehavior.Return;

        for (int counter = 0; counter < args.Arguments.Count; counter++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("arg{0} is {1}",counter,args.Arguments[counter]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("On Entry");
    }
}
```

I have cast exception when I return `new ReturnState<object>..` and Postshop try cast to `ReturnState<Person>` but can't.

Comment: And the exact exception details are...?

Comment: This method doesn't make a lot of sense? What are u trying to achieve? Because as it shows there you are just overiding your return value as soon as the method is entered? Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Next to that, you can make an abstract type, change your method to public static ReturnState<AbstractType> GetPerson() Then your type Person that is derived from AbstractType (which you should give a meaningfull name.) Will be able to be returned. And in postsharp you will be able to return something in the likes of ReturnSate<NullType>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's because you're creating a `ReturnState<object>`, which isn't a `ReturnState<Person>`.

Options:

- Change your `PostModerateAttribute` to find out the *correct* return type, and create an instance of that instead.
- Hard-code `PostModerateAttribute` to return `ReturnState<Person>`
- Change the return type (and expression) of your object to `ReturnState<object>`

Comment: I want to return anonymous type ,I can't use your options.

Comment: @Amirhosseingholzam: Why not? You can construct an instance of an anonymous type by reflection, which falls into option 1. Note that your question doesn't show an anonymous type at all.

Comment: You right. Options 1 is correct ,I know that but reflection is slow.

Comment: @Amirhosseingholzam: There are ways to make it not particularly slow - such as building (and then reusing) a delegate to create the instance. But your question seems to be changing a lot, and you shouldn't assume that something is too slow before you've actually tried it.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jon Skeet, You can show me a good reference for this case.

Comment: @Amirhosseingholzam: Not easily, with so much of the question up in the air - we don't know what `ReturnState` looks like, whether it could be changed to that `Succeed` doesn't need to be explicitly set, etc. I suggest you try doing this the simple way first, check the performance, then post a new question if it's too slow.